# Android messages deleting themselves/ Not showing up!

Tags: sms

All my messages were working fine until a few weeks ago when i could message everyone and receive messages.

Now one of my contacts can receive messages from me and can send messages successfully to me, on my phone the message shows up in notifications but whenever i go into the app they aren't there also, when i message my contact they receive the text fine but i can't see it on my phone.

The only odd thing i have seen is that the time stamp is the 8th Nov 2016, today is the 7th.

How can i fix this so i can see inbound and outbound messages?

Comment: Well, it is 8th November in parts of the world, right now, as we speak, (so to speak). It is all dependent on the relevant timezone to dictate that. Have you checked that? Also, have you changed from automatic time, automatic date, and automatic timezone to self-settting? Do you have the settings correct?

Comment: @wbogacz I am in the GMT zone so it is 6:15 over here and the time is set to Network provided date and time.

Comment: You might need to clear the data/storage for SMS.  Do you have much free space on your device?

Comment: @MatthewRead yes i have plenty free space. By clearing the database i take it you mean "Clear data" under settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the "date" i had sent it on was in the future.
I must have been getting coins in a game or something, so the messages where, according to android, in the future so i could not receive messages from that contact until the 8th.

To fix this problem if you have it either:

- Wait for the date to arrive
- Delete the messages from the "future" (Not tested)
- Set the time on your phone to past the time stamp on the messages

Side note - You can still receive messages in the notifications bar, just not in messages.

You can also send messages, they just don't show up.